# Bulk remove tags * tag content in VS code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I am translating a document from word to HTML - this is painful... however I have found a way to speed this up, but it has left my HTML very chunky i.e.

```
<p class="MsoNormal" align="left" style="margin-top:0cm;margin-right:0cm;
        margin-bottom:12.0pt;margin-left:0cm;text-align:left;text-indent:0cm;
        line-height:115%;vertical-align:baseline"><span lang="EN-GB">To comply with any
        legal or regulatory requirements.</span></p>
```

Ugly as sin right....

So what I am wondering is:

In VS code is there a way to select large amounts of html i.e.

[image]

And then run a command via the command pallet, or search and replace to say.

Remove the style attribute and all of the content instead of it?

--

Im sure this must have been asked before but have not found a way to do this and am trying to work smarter not harder.

Thanks -
W

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing I would do, noting your final thought there that this must have been answered would be to do a cursory search on SO before posting. But since it's here, the easiest way I have found is to either use the MS Word's own export functionality to HTML:

Go to the file menu.
Select Save as.
In the drop-down file type box select, Web Page, Filtered.
Click Save.

If that does not produce the output you want, there are free services online where you can paste rich content and have the app rewrite it for you in html, such as this site: https://wordtohtml.net/

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply - Words inbuilt "save to html" function is what has caused the abundance of code, I did just try the filtered version but no change... WordtoHtml requires payment, using the pro version (or randomly removing words...) - so that option is out. And I also did do a check on SO prior to posting - which is why im supprised this question hasn't been found before (or maybe under another name). 
I don't suppose you have any other suggestions? I was thinking Regex in a specific search